# Facebook Pulling the wrong image

Tags: facebook, image, web

An easy one I hope, I just can't find the solution online, I am using the following code -

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="626317029" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Derby West | Local Business Advertising" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.derbywest.co.uk/images/fblogo-derby-west.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.derbywest.co.uk/index.php" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Local Advertising for Local Business" />
```

But Facebook insists on use the first image (which is the background) when my site is referenced. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me, after putting it in the Debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.derbywest.co.uk%2Findex.php

If some OG tags don´t work as expected, it´s good to test the URL in the Debugger. It will tell you what´s wrong, and it refreshes the data.

Comment: Looks good mate, but it still pulls the sky background ahead of the business logo (when I try and type the web address in to a page, or message chat) and then it doesn't pull the right image in terms of size just the larger version used on the site?

Comment: weird, for me it looks perfect, it only takes that one specified picture. maybe it takes some time to refresh for messages chats. did you try to just share the link in your stream?